# The list ordering

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

Does anyone know how to obtain 'list2' from 'list1'?
... ... because I got confused.
The algorithm will be used for very large lists.

```
list1 = {{1, 35, 3}, {1, 896, 1}, {2, 3, 999}, {1, 212, 5}, {1, 243, 1}, {3, 2, 88}, {1, 903, 3}, {35, 1, 9}, {1, 914, 1}, {1, 925, 2}, {896, 1, -6}};

list2={{{1, 35, 3}, {35, 1, 9}}, {{1, 896, 1}, {896, 1, -6}}, {{2, 3, 999}, {3, 2, 88}}, {1, 212,5}, {1, 243, 1}, {1, 903, 3}, {1, 914, 1}, {1, 925, 2}};
```

Of course, the order doesn't matter. The most important thing is that elements #1[[1]] == #2[[2]] || # 1[[2]] == #2[[1]] are in one sublist.

Comment: `Gather[list1, #1[[1]] == #2[[2]] && #1[[2]] == #2[[1]] &] /. {x_} :> x`

Answer (score 5):

```
Gather[list1, #[[;;2]] == Reverse @  #2[[;;2]] &] /. {x_} :> x
```

> ```
> {{{1, 35, 3}, {35, 1, 9}}, 
> {{1, 896, 1}, {896, 1, -6}}, 
> {{2, 3,  999}, {3, 2, 88}}, 
> {1, 212, 5}, {1, 243, 1}, {1, 903, 3}, {1, 914, 1}, {1, 925, 2}}
> ```

If input list is a list of triples, you can also use `Most[#]` in place of `#[[;; 2]] &`.

We can also construct a graph on `list1` using [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) and find its [`ConnectedComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedComponents.html) to get the same groupings:

```
relation = #[[;; 2]] == Reverse @ #2[[;; 2]] &;

ConnectedComponents @ RelationGraph[relation, list1] /. {x_} :> x
```

> ```
> {{{2, 3, 999}, {3, 2, 88}},
>  {{1, 896, 1}, {896, 1, -6}}, 
>  {{1, 35,  3}, {35, 1, 9}}, 
>  {1, 925, 2}, {1, 914, 1}, {1, 903, 3}, {1, 243, 1}, {1, 212, 5}}
> ```